# How does --scale help in the docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, scaling

We have an option in docker-compose called `--scale` which can be used when we want to have multiple instances of a specific container (e.g. Redis)

Since docker-compose is used to make all containers up & running in one machine, how does it make sense that we create multiple instances of a specific container in the same machine?

Either one instance uses the whole resources or multiple instances use them. What is the difference?

Comment: I'm not an expert so I'm not going to write a full answer, but the general idea as I understand it is that you would be creating multiple instances of a service, so incoming requests can be handled in parallel.  Each container is its own process.  By scaling to multiple instances, incoming requests can be distributed across the different containers and run in parallel.  Assuming of course that the service in each container isn't individually maxing out a core or using all available RAM on the host.

Comment: Two places it can make sense are with single-threaded language runtimes, or if you're using Docker's Swarm cluster environment to run on multiple hosts.